# Sending a chat to Google IM User

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I want to build a simple web-interface application that can send/receive chat messages to/from GTalk/GMail users. I have been looking at some options like BOSH over XMPP, imified, Google App Engine etc.

I wanted your views on which is the most efficient among all out there and which has a mimimum learning curve since I need this for a very limited functionality. Also, if there is any other way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this link](https://github.com/EmiteGWT) which provides an GWT client for XMPP connections.

You could also use [Smack library](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) to make one Java client and run it as an applet.

I've seen some Ruby on Rails tutorials on how to use ruby libraries to exchange XMPP messages, a bit of google could put you in the right path.